# Map LDAP specific attribute containing roles to Keycloak roles and vice versa

Tags: keycloak, openldap

I have a LDAP connection set up in my Keycloak and in my LDAP the roles are contained under a specific attribute (Of course these are not really roles from the technical point of view)

What I want to achieve is to map these user attribute roles to roles in keycloak.

With the custom mapper implementation, which is similar to the implementation here

https://github1s.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/HEAD/federation/ldap/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/ldap/mappers/HardcodedLDAPRoleStorageMapper.java

the problem i am facing is that Keycloak maps the "roles" user model attribute to "userRole" ldap attribute Only the first value gets added and the others will be lost. i am thinking that perhaps it might be important to override the method onRegisterUserToLDAP?

Any pointers will be appreciated.